# 'trap' not working after 'exec' command

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am developing a monitoring program using bash. This program will be running continuously, and if I update the bash code, this should rerun the new code without exiting(Basically hot upgrade).

I tried to do this by using SIGUSR2 and exec-ing the same script again.

It is working correctly the first time, the SIGUSR2 signal is caught and the new script is exec-ed. But after the first exec, it's not responding to SIGUSR2 anymore.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

VERSION=v1
upgrade()
{
    export GOT_UPGRADED=true
    echo "Upgrading..."
    exec $HOME/workspace/test/upgrade_test
}

init()
{
    if [[ $GOT_UPGRADED != true ]]; then
        # won't initialize again, if it's got upgraded.
        echo "Initializing..."
    fi
}

monitor()
{
    echo "$VERSION: Monitoring..."
}

trap upgrade SIGUSR2 # if SIGUSR2 is received, upgrade.

init
while true; do
    monitor
    sleep 1
done;
```

Sample Run:

```bsh
shell1: ./upgrade_test
Initializing...
v1: Monitoring...
v1: Monitoring...
v1: Monitoring...
v1: Monitoring...
v1: Monitoring...
Upgrading...                  # Sent from shell2
v1: Monitoring...
v1: Monitoring...
v1: Monitoring...
v1: Monitoring...

Meanwhile in shell2:
pkill -SIGUSR2 -f upgrade_test; # here it got upgraded
pkill -SIGUSR2 -f upgrade_test; # THE PROBLEM: doesn't work anymore
```

How can I keep the SIGUSR2 hanlder working even after exec?

Thanks,

Comment: `exec` replaces the shell, what remains to execute the trap? Why use `exec`?

Comment: `exec` command is running the same program again, so can't that shell trap SIGUSR2?
I am trying to find a way to update the program without closing it, hence using `exec`, please let me know if some other way is there.

Comment: Actually running this as `bash ./upgrade_test` instead of just `./upgrade_test` solved the problem. What happened here?

Comment: Is bash the same as `/bin/bash`? What does `command -v bash` report?

Comment: You are right! `/bin/bash` and `bash` are running different bash. `/bin/bash` is v3.2.57, `/usr/local/bin/bash` is v5.0.18, which is ran by `bash` command. So this could be an issue that is fixed in newer bash?

Comment: Seems so. After you switch to `bash ./upgrade_test`, how many times can you successfully use `SIGUSR2` to get the trap to run? Twice? More times?

Comment: Twice. I guess since the `exec program` command is running old bash again. So after updating that to `exec bash program`, the trap is running multiple times. Thanks for pointing it out. Anyway, in the production machines, we are using bash v4, and it's working fine there.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for `bash` version 4.4

```
#!/bin/bash

########################################################################
#
trapped()
{
    echo "Oh oh I'm trapped"
    exec "$0" "$@"

    echo "exec failed: $0 $*"
    exit 1
}

########################################################################
# Go
#
trap trapped SIGUSR2

echo "Running new instance as PID $$"
while :
do
    read -p "$(date): " -t 120 X; ss=$?; echo
    [[ $ss -eq 1 ]] && exit
done
```

Running this as `/tmp/trap.sh`,

```
Running new instance as PID 3899
11 Mar 2021 10:29:22: Oh oh I'm trapped
Running new instance as PID 3899
11 Mar 2021 10:29:36: Oh oh I'm trapped
Running new instance as PID 3899
11 Mar 2021 10:29:38:
```